# I want to found RHS = LHS in php

Tags: php

I want to check the given right hand side equation is equal to the left hand side or not. The value of $x = (19/30).

`(((6*($x)) - 5)/(7 - (3*($x)))) = ((4 - (8 * $x))/((4 * $x) + 2))`

I had tried below mentioned code, but it shown the RHS value is greater than LHS.

```
<?php

function check($m, $n) 
{      
    $rhs = abs($m); 
    $lhs = abs($n); 
    if($rhs > $lhs){ 
        echo "$m <strong style='color:red;'>is greater than</strong> $n"; 
    }
    elseif($rhs < $lhs) {
        echo "$m <strong style='color:blue;'>is smaller than</strong> $n"; 
    }
    else{
        echo "$m <strong style='color:green;'>is equal</strong> $n";
    } 
} 


// $m = ((6*(19/30)) - 5)/(7 - (3*(19/30)));
// $n = (4 - (8 * (19/30)))/((4 * (19/30)) + 2); 

$x = 19/30;
$m = abs(((6*($x)) - 5)/(7 - (3*($x))));
$n = abs((4 - (8 * $x))/((4 * $x) + 2)); 
check($m, $n); 

?>
```

**The output:**
`0.23529411764706 is greater than 0.23529411764706`

Comment: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/06/the-php-floating-point-precision-is-wrong-by-default/#:~:text=As%20you%20can%20see%20the,called%20a%20%E2%80%9Cfloating%20point%20%E2%80%9C.

Comment: Got it....Thanks